# Confused about git branch

Tags: git

I have a question about git branches. If I have for example 2 branch. The master branch and a second branch, for example secondBranch.

When I create a third branch, say thirdbranch. If I write the command in the master branch or the second branch secondBranch, the result is identical ? will the branch always drift from master?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

whenever issuing the command `git branch thirdbranch`, without specifying "the branch to use as the base", the active branch is used.

If `master` and `secondBranch` are already equivalent branches, then it does not matter from which branch you issue your `git branch thirdbranch` command from, as both branches are at the same head commit.